# How to star a folder in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

I have a Google Drive Folder, which was shared with me via link (I guess it's set to `Anyone with link in Organisation can View/Edit`). When I click the link, I get into the Google Drive web UI, with the folder content listed. I can star any contained file/folder, but I don't see any way to star the shared folder (the root folder) itself.

If it was explicitly shared with me, then I could find it under `Shared with me` and star it there. But it's not the case. If I just search it by the name, I get into same view as through the link, where I see the content, but I don't see a way to star the folder itself.

I am essentially looking for a way how to make this shared folder click-accessible (without remembering the name or looking up the link each time). If there is other way to do this, other than starring, I would appreciate it as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same problem. In the new web interface you can click the button with folder name and select the Add star item. However, for me this does not have any effect in web interface (the star is lost after page refresh) nor in Android Google Drive app, though it miraculously works in Google Drive app on iPad.
Apparently Google needs some more time to make this usable...

Comment: Good point @alefnula, the new interface solves this. You can even just right-click it and select "Add to My Drive" and it will appear wherever you select in your drive dir structure (while still maintaining the original owner). It even appeared on my iOS, but I had to refresh there (by pulling down) and (not sure if it matters), I first created another folder from iOS, because I was not able to see any folders there at all - then this folder appeared in Web interface and after few moments other folders appeared on iOS.